# Adjust UILabel Dynamically Within UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I would like to adjust the number of lines in a UILabel dynamically. For example, there could be a long string or a short string. If there are less than 10 characters, there should be one line. If there are 10-20 characters, it should be two lines. This UILabel is inside of a UITableViewCell. Currently, if there is a long string, then the UILabel just shows "..." wherever it runs out of space, so the string is cut off. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`nameOfLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

0 is supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: For some reason doing that makes no difference to the output!

Comment: do you have constraints set?

Comment: Also, do you have a custom class for the cell? You may be able to override the `prepareForReuse()` function to set that attribute to the label.

Comment: If I have a custom class for the cell where the label is declared as a variable, what needs to go there?

Comment: What is posted above is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

First set numberOfLines to 0 for that UILabel from Storyboard

Than set estimated height for your UITableView

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 108.0
```

Than Add heightForRowAt method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Hope it Help!

Comment: It still does not have a multi-line label even when it should!

Comment: You have to set constraint from storyboard for that UILabel on Top, Bottom, Left and Right to make it work.

Comment: Look at this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnD2XMqDhfI) for How to set Constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Constaints from Top Left Right Buttom of label and label.numberOfLine = 0 make it dynamically resizable according to dynamic content.[image: Contraints ScreenShot]

[image: Number Of Line ScreenShot]

Comment: How do I actually add the constraints shown in your above image? I've never done that before.

Comment: just add normal left right top bottom contraint so it can be stretch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give constraints to tableview cell's label leading, trailing, top and bottom like below...

[image]

Also set label's number of lines to zero and line breaking mode to word wrap.

And in your main view controller just add this line...

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

The above line automatically calculates the cell height as per its content.

Answer (score 0):

- Assign and implement tableview dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

-

**Objective C:**

```
// in ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

  @property IBOutlet UITableView * table;

@end

// in ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    self.table.delegate = self;

    self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

**Swift:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) with respect to its superview/ cell container.
- *Optional*: Set minimum height for label, if you want minimum vertical area covered by label, even if there is no data.

[image]

**Note**: If you've more than one labels (UIElements) with dynamic length, which should be adjusted according to its content size: Adjust 'Content Hugging and Compression Resistance Priority` for labels which you want to expand/compress with higher priority.

Comment: FYI: when `self.table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;` is set you don't need to implement `heightForRowAt ` method.

Comment: @MahendraGP - Yes, you are right, I added all possible options that help in achieving result which he/she wants. Thank you for your remark,.. It will light a notice to OP, what should he/she consider while designing his cell and label.

Comment: Your response is very helpful. How do I actually add the constraints shown in your bottom image? I've never done that before.